# Web audio player without stopping

Tags: audio

I'm searching for web audio player (that can play RTMP stream too)
But i really don't know how to make the session that the player can't stop while you browse other pages. I mean players like soundcloud.com or beatport.com
I have a player that can play RTMP stream, but i really don't know how to make it unstoppable  I tried to search here and in google, but cant find any result